# Does Moving Ink Speed increase ink usage?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

I picked up the Moving Ink Speed chip which states

> Increases movement speed when moving while inking with a roller or brush.

Since moving faster with a brush would paint more surface area in less time, does increasing my movement speed also increase how quickly I use up ink with a roller or brush?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't, movement speed has nothing to do with ink consumption. You'll end up painting the same surface, just in less time.

Comment: If you move faster with a brush, you paint more surface area in less time.

Comment: I mean, considering the same painted area, you will consume the same ink, just in less time

Comment: @pinckerman Well that's the question, right?  Does ink get consumed at a fixed rate regardless of movement speed (in which case this would be a strict buff), or is it relative to how much ink is output (which would make this both a buff and a nerf)?  Chips such as the one that increases the number of shots fired in a single splatling charge *does not* increase the ink consumption of that charge, even though it outputs more ink

Comment: @ChaseSandmann "Does ink get consumed at a fixed rate regardless of movement speed?", and in my opinion yes. You may think that ink consumption has increased, but it's just because you have travelled more space. Just a speculation, that's why I'm not posting an answer.